# android.permission.WAKE_LOCK is Automatically enabled

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-permissions, flutter-dependencies

I have developed a flutter app for Android and iOS. It was sent to a security audit by the customer. In the Audit, they said `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` is enabled and its a security risk. They recommended the following

> It is recommended to consider each feature provided by the respective
> parameter and assess the business requirement in enabling the same.

Well, I dont know how this permission can be a security risk, but at the sametime I have not enabled such in `manifest` file. Below is my Android manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.appname">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="MY APP"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Below is my pubspecs.yaml file

```
name: MyApp
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.2+3

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  google_fonts: ^0.2.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  json_annotation: ^3.0.1
  provider: ^4.0.4
  badges: ^1.1.1
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.13
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+3
  intl: ^0.16.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  
  build_runner: ^1.7.4
  json_serializable: ^3.2.5
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/icon.jpg"


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/logo.png
    - assets/images/lock_24px.png
    - assets/images/email_24px.png
    - assets/images/shopping_cart_48px.png
    - assets/images/logo_2.jpg
    - assets/images/fish1.png
    - assets/images/fish2.png
    - assets/icons/account-filled.png
    - assets/icons/account-not_filled.png
    - assets/icons/history-filled.png
    - assets/icons/history-not_filled.png
    - assets/icons/home-filled.png
    - assets/icons/home-not_filled.png
    - assets/icons/notifications-not_filled.png
    - assets/icons/notifications-filled.png
    - assets/images/loading_image2.gif

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf
    - family: Ma Shan Zheng
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/MaShanZheng-Regular.ttf
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Whats going on here? Maybe the permission is auto added by one of the plugins I use? In that case, how to remove it?

Comment: it's prolly from firebase

Comment: @Selvin: Thank you for the reply. Is there any reference to see thats its coming from Firebase?

Comment: well, not from intl, shared_preferences, badges, provider, json_annotation, fonts, icons 
 nor from your code ... so it's firebase ... also WAKE_LOCK  has nothing with security but rather with on battery life(if  abused)

Comment: @Selvin: Yes, Also I found references which says that by default this permission is added if target SDK is API Level 23. Also android no longer consider this as a dangerous action.

Answer (score -1):

First examine the merged manifest (check which library is adding this permission) - change 'Text' to 'Merged Manifest'. Review if you need the library and if you do, you can argument that third party library is using it.
To remove it, add it like this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: I opened the manifest in APK. The permission was there, even though I did not add it

Comment: You need to check it in the project (not the APK) there you will see option to display "Merged Manifest" containing all the participants who contribute to your manifest (next to you).